# authenticating google analytics api

Tags: api, rest, google-analytics

I am using query explorer to get the API constructed in google analytics, but this comes with token. I don't know how can I get a token or authenticate so it never expires.

I am not using any app, just want when I hit browser with API I get JSON results that's it.

Please someone please help me to authenticate the API I get from query explorer in GA.

Comment: Please explain your question in more details. Have you already got a token from GOOGLE?  A token is like an admission ticket for a concert. You need one to get in.   You need a token - otherwise you will not get access.  Please see: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization

Comment: Query explorer gives me a token but that expires after 60 mins, I dont want it to expire at all so i can fetch data whenever i want

Comment: Infact i dont know what to use in the link you shared to get access token so it doesnt expires or gets refreshed automatically and my rest api will still give me json results when i hit from my browser. Is it possible for you to send me steps i can follow to get this done. Let me know if i can also share my screen and show you my issue on skype-sanchit.singh1990

Answer (score 0):

The query explorer is only a tryout platform and DOES NOT produce tokens for  indefinite use.

There is a step by step setup for this:
https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=analytics&credential=client_key&pli=1

Comment: Hi Alexander, how can i get the API to work with a token  that doesnt expire,
The link you mentioned doesnt help in getting token that doesnt expire.

which one should i use from below link to get token that doesnt change:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/authorization

Comment: use https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=analytics&credential=client_key&pli=1